# React Router point visitor to a static website

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app and I use the react-router-dom to route the requests to the appropriate page of the React app like so:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={Redirect User To Static HTML} />
        <Route path="/somethingElse" element={<SomeReactComponent/>} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

As you can see the `example.com/seomthingElse` is pointing to a React component. I want the root requests (`example.com/`) to be redirected to a static website that I host in an S3 buckets on AWS.

If that helps, the static website is generated by [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's possible, what you can do is this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={Redirect User To Static HTML} />
        <Route path="/somethingElse" element={<SomeReactComponent/>} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

const SomeReactComponent = (props) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {}
    window.location.href = YOUR URL;
  },[]);

  return <h3> Redirecting.... </h3>
}
```